# Should a tag for partial derivatives be created?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Over time I've answered several questions related to similar confusions surrounding partial derivatives. The latest one is [Confusion regarding partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125225/125246#comment289491_125246), and several other examples are linked to in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101011/6622). These question have a lot in common, and I'm wondering whether it would make sense to create a tag [partial-derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-derivatives) for them, which would be more specific than the existing [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) and [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives). I've never created a tag before and am unsure whether this would be too specific – what do you think?

Comment: Would PDE's be part of this tag?

Comment: @TheChaz: it better not be. There is already a (pde) tag, and questions actually about pdes are much different from those about partial derivatives.

Comment: @WillieWong: Then it's a good thing I'm not in charge! There would probably be only 5-6 tags... :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Do we count upvotes on your question as indication that the community agrees that the tag should be created, or just an indication that users of this site find this topic important enough to discuss? If the tag is created, we will need to clarify whether it is only for computations of partial derivatives; similar discussion for some other tags is here: [Tags derivatives, integral, limit only for computation questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/tags-derivatives-integral-limit-only-for-computation-questions).